# Can I re-forge an item with only platinum in Terraria

Tags: terraria

So I have the Zenith and I wanna re-forge it but I have mostly platinum can I do that or no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All purchases in Terraria give you change.

Additional, all coins can be freely split and combined via crafting.